# Intersection of Random Subspace and Hypercube

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose that $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a random linear subspace of dimension $k < n$.  I am interested in the event that $A$ intersects the hypercube $[-1,\ 1]^n$ at a specific face.

In other words, the event that there is some vector $a\in A$ with particular configuration of $r$ entries equal to $1$ and $s$ entries equal to $-1$ (the remaining entries are all in the range $(-1, 1)$) with $r+s\leq k$.

In particular, I am interested in calculating or bounding the probability of such an event. The distribution of $A$ can be chosen as any continuous distribution that makes this tractable/easy.

I would appreciate any pointers on this as I'm unsure where to start.
thanks :)

Comment: Just to make sure, the linear subspaces do go through the origin, right? (I realize that all *subspaces* must, some people just use the term a little recklessly). If that's the case, my intuition suggests that any one-dimensional subspace intersects a given $d$-dimensional face with a probability of $\dfrac{2}{\text{the number of $d$-dimensional faces}}$, assuming the direction of the one-dimensional subspace has a uniform distribution. I'm not sure if this would help us with higher-dimensional subspaces, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip ahead, past the break, for the condensed argument and conclusion. I'm only focusing on the case when the faces are as large as possible (facets). I suspect (but haven't thought much about confirming) that the full story can be obtained, *fairly* straightforwardly, once enough is known about the case of facets, together with the combinatorial aspects of a cube.

I'll explain my viewpoint on the problem, focusing on the standard cube in $\Bbb R^3$. We'll abstract from there.

For the moment, let's focus on $1$-dimensional subspaces. I'm going to assume we're choosing a unit vector, uniformly at random. Thus, we have a unit sphere's worth (not entirely true; but we'll correct soon) of choices of directions for our subspace. And, instead of working with the cube, we'll work with a spherical cube (by scaling each point on the cube to have length $1$).

The $6$ faces of spherical cube partition the unit sphere into $6$ regions of equal area; thus, the probability that a unit vector lies in a particular region (corresponding to a particular face) is $$\dfrac{\text{area of region}}{\text{area of sphere}} = \frac{1}{6}.$$

But wait, there's more! This is only the probability that a particular point on the unit sphere is in a certain region. Each $1$-dimensional subspace determines *two* antipodal points on the sphere, so our probability is really $\frac{1}{3}$, essentially by identifying opposite faces of the cube.

Since our formula for probability involves areas, the probability of a $1$-dimensional subspace going precisely through an edge or vertex is $0$.

I'll leave serious thought about $2$-dimensional subspaces to you. Essentially each subspace determines a "belt" of four faces and there are three such belts, with each face contained in two belts; this leads to a probability of $\frac{2}{3}$. Thinking hard about this step lead naturally to thinking about higher dimensions and generalizing the preceding thoughts.

---

- We may ignore subspaces going through "small dimensional" faces (vertices, edges, etc) of a cube, as the probability of such a thing happening with a randomly chosen subspace is $0$.
- Any$^1$ subspace of dimension $d$ intersects $[-1, 1]^n$ in exactly $2d$ facets (faces of dimension $n - 1$), these $2d$ facets splitting into $d$ pairs of opposite facets (this was the hardest part of the argument for me to figure out). Thus, any subspace of dimension $d$ uniquely determines $d$ pairs of opposite facets, and there are $n$ such facet-pairs.
- Thus the probability that a random $d$-dimensional subspace intersects a particular facet of the cube is exactly the probability that a given facet-pair is contained in a set of $d$ facet-pairs.
- There are ${{n - 1} \choose {d - 1}}$ ways to choose $d$ facet-pairs of an $n$-dimensional cube containing a given facet-pair, and ${n \choose d}$ total ways to choose $d$ facet pairs. The probability of including a particular facet, then, simplifies quite nicely to $\frac{d}{n}$, which suggests to me there's a more streamlined argument!

$^1$ "Any" here means any subspace that intersects the interior of a facet whenever it intersects a face of that facet; we're ignoring the subspaces like those in $\Bbb R^3$ that go through two vertices, or two opposite edges, of a cube, without intersecting the interior of a facet.